# In asp.net how to play Multiple swf files in single Object control

Tags: asp.net

In aspx pages i had a single object and plays the .swf file.but i need to change dynamically the object will change another swf file depends on Impressions.

Answer (score 1):

You can only load a single swf file for a single

You have 2 options:

1) Dyamically change the url to the SWF File

2) Load a stub Flash file (ie source always stays the same) which then loads in other SWF files from the stub as required.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Change the source url the object points to depending on the rules your impressions dictate.